# ClientTemplate expression to include javascript conditional

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Have been using Kendo UI MVC for a while now and need to put some conditional logic on a checkbox that is in one field of the grid.

The fields in the grid that need to be evaluated are

Going off the example here 
https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-display-checkboxes-in-ajax-bound-grids

```cs
columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).ClientTemplate(
    "# if (HasIcon == true) { #" +
        "<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Content/icons/") + "#= ProductID #.png' alt='#= ProductName # icon' />" +
    "# } else { #" +
        "#: ProductName #" +
    "# } #"
);
```

How do I format the test within the conditional to use a grid field value ?
eg
 testing if ProductID is a specific value like this?

```cs
columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).ClientTemplate(
    "# if (#= ProductID # == 123) { #" +
        "<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Content/icons/") + "#= ProductID #.png' alt='#= ProductName # icon' />" +
    "# } else { #" +
        "#: ProductName #" +
    "# } #"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

due to the sometimes complex nature of client templates, I personally tend to use the javascript function method
    `columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).ClientTemplate("#= getProductIcon(data, 
    Url.Content("~/Content/icons/")#);`

then in a js script block

```
function getProductIcon(data, imgUrl) {
   if (data.ProductID == 123)
      return "<img src='" + imgUrl + data.ProductID + ".png' alt='" + data.ProductName + " icon' />";
   else
      return data.ProductName;
}
```

just make sure your script is loaded before the grid is instantiated otherwise you'll run into `getProductIcon` undefined or some similar error. Also it's easier to throw a debugger on your javascript function and really see what's going on and verify the data in/out.

Excuse any typos in the above, I'm not at a location where I can validate the razor syntax at the moment.